# Cascade deleting with EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework

Have listed classes in model(simplified):

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Topics = new HashSet<Topic>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? Category_Id { get; set; }//id for Parent category

    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}

public partial class Topic
{
    public Topic()
    {
        Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Category_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Model here:

```
public partial class EntityModel : DbContext
{
    public EntityModel()
        : base("name=EntityModelContext")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("Context Created");
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Topic> Topic { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Topics)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Category)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.Category_Id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Topic>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Posts)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Topic)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.Topic_Id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

So problem:
when i trying to delete sub category (that have NOT NULL Category_Id) => delete successful, but when i need to delete root category(Category_Id = NULL) there is an exeption: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint “FK_Topic_Category”.
Yes, I can delete reffered topics in the root category before and then delete category. But want to know why in root case cascade delete not work.

Answer (score 0):

ok, just added ON DELETE CASCADE to children entity's FK in DB annotation.

Comment: Hi Renat. How did you add ON DELETE CASCADE to the FK? I'm having the same problem but none of the solutions I've looked at seem to fix it. I'm using EF Core 2.0 on SQLite.